# Restore backup from Docker to Neo4j

Tags: docker, neo4j

I have a Neo4j Docker backup folder. The structure looks like the following:

```
Neo4j
   |-data 
       |-databases
           |-graph.db
       |-dbms
   |-plugins
```

I would like to restore this backup to a Neo4j 3.0.7 installed on a Windows 10 machine because I decided not to use Neo4j with Docker anymore.

I copied the contents of `Neo4j\data\databases\graph.db` to `Neo4j\default.graphdb`

When I click the start button I get this error.

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@11841b5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.`
```

What I have tried so far:

- Since the Neo4j Docker image is version 3.0.3 and I'm using 3.0.7, I uncommented the line `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` in `neo4j.conf`

The Neo4j Docker image version is 3.0.3.

Are there any additional procedures that need to be performed when restoring a backup from a Neo4j Docker image?

Comment: Is there anything in `Neo4j/default.graphdb/logs/`?